# How to do the calculation with std::transform

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a void function that takes as arguments iterators to the start and the end of a set of points (Setiterator set_begin, Setiterator set_end),a query point to perform some calculations and a iterator to the beginnig of a set of points ( where I am going to add the results)

```
void computedist(Setiterator set_begin, Setiterator set_end,
Vector const& query_point, DistanceIterator dist_begin )
{
    std::transform(set_begin, set_end, dist_begin, calculation);

}
```

I have read that with std::transform I can do that calculations over the whole set of points, but I don't know how should I define the calculation to be done, as I am new to C++.

In this case, I want to compute the distance of the points to the query point:

I guess that my calculation should look like this

```
double calc_dist(double query_point, double point_of_the_set){
     double dist;
     dist = fabs(query_point - point_of_the_set);
     return dist;
```

But I don't know how should I give the arguments to the function, since I am new to working with iterators.

Thank's!

Comment: It sounds like [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) may be more appropriate for you.

Comment: What is type `Vector` and what does it have to do with `double`?

Comment: I want to return the dist value as a double

Comment: @NathanOliver with std::for_each I can't specify where to put the output values

Comment: @Praderas I'm sorry I though you were coming up with a single output.  If you need one output per element than `std::transform` seems logical.

Comment: Sorry, I get confused with C++, type    Vector is just a value

Comment: Use a lambda such as `[&query_point](auto& x){ return fabs(query_point - x); }` as the 4th argument to `std::transform`.

Comment: I guess `auto& x` is something that points to the value in the set of points, how can I specify it?

Comment: The compiler will work out the correct type of `auto` for you (i.e. it corresponds to the types stored in your set) so it is not necessary to specify it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flavor of `std::transform` you are calling expects a UnaryOp function to call, to which it passes '*iterator' by const reference and expects a return value of the `iterator::value_type` which it writes to `*dest`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using valtype = int;
    std::vector<valtype> v1 { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<valtype> v2(v1.size());
    std::transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(),
        [] (const valtype& in) { return in * 2; });

    for (auto& val : v2)
        std::cout << val << '\n';
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/CUUlvA